# Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a website now using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and I used the toolbox of `"createUserWizard"`. Then I put the `userId` for my `"CustomerInfo"` table to the `"data type=uniqueidentifier"` because I need to link it to the user name in the aspnet_ table.

Later on, I need to link my `"Order"` table to the `"CustomerInfo"` table so I put my `orderId data type=uniqueidentifier`. Then, I plan insert my order details to the `"Order"` table but I have the problem of:

> "Implicit conversion from data type
>   sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not
>   allowed. Use the  CONVERT function to
>   run this query".

I search and find some answer like datatype of the parameter set to "Empty"or delete it. but then I have this error

> " Conversion failed when converting from character string to uniqueidentifier."

This is my SQL

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Order] WHERE [orderId] = @orderId" 
                                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Order] ([orderId], [userId], [Services], [PickUpDate], [PickUpTime], [SpecialDate], [SpecialTime]) VALUES (@orderId, @userId, @Services, @PickUpDate, @PickUpTime, @SpecialDate, @SpecialTime)" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Order]" 

                                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Order] SET [userId] = @userId, [Services] = @Services, [PickUpDate] = @PickUpDate, [PickUpTime] = @PickUpTime, [SpecialDate] = @SpecialDate, [SpecialTime] = @SpecialTime WHERE [orderId] = @orderId">
                                    <DeleteParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="orderId" Type="Object" />
                                    </DeleteParameters>
                                    <InsertParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="orderId" Type="Object" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="Object" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="Services" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="PickUpDate" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="PickUpTime" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="SpecialDate" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="SpecialTime" Type="String" />
                                    </InsertParameters>
                                    <UpdateParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="Object" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="Services" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="PickUpDate" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="PickUpTime" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="SpecialDate" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="SpecialTime" Type="String" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="orderId" Type="Object" />
                                    </UpdateParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now that I think of it, maybe there is a problem with my code in vb.
I will put it here, please tell me how to do the correct way of inserting data to the database.

```
Protected Sub OrderButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrderButton.Click
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters(0).DefaultValue = Now
    SqlDataSource1.Insert()
    Response.Redirect("~/Customer/AfterOrder.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to post your SQL if you want someone to tell you what's wrong with it. We'll also need the definitions of the columns in your table.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to insert GUID from your code, you should make parameter type GUID

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ParamName" DbType="Guid" />
```

And you should pass GUID value as (c#):

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ParamName"].DefaultValue = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

If you want to pass a string value, you have to use `CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'YOUR VALUE')` in the insert query like this:

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Order] ([UserId], [etc]) 
VALUES (CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@UserId), @etc)"
```