# Inserting uniqueidentifier type in database. Conversion error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I tried remove (Type="Object") and it still generate error in Password when inserting data.

**TABLE** 
**ProfileId**   int
**Firstname**   nvarchar
**Lastname**    nvarchar
**Contact**     nvarchar
**Username**    nvarchar
**Password**    uniqueidentifier

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SanitexConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblProfile]"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblProfile] (ProfileId,FirstName,LastName,Contact,UserName,Password) VALUES(@ProfileId,@FirstName,@LastName,@Contact,@UserName,@Password)"
        >
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProfileId" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Lastname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Contact" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: what error is it generating? generating it by doing what?

Comment: "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier." when i insert data.

Comment: Can you add the schema of `tblProfile` to the question(including data types)?

Comment: try with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478847/implicit-conversion-from-data-type-sql-variant-to-uniqueidentifier-is-not-allowe

Answer (score 1):

The only string which can be successfully inserted in `uniqueidentifier` column is in the form **xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**, in which each **x** is a **hexadecimal** digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example, **6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF** is a valid `uniqueidentifier` value.

- Hence, make sure that the password you are inserting is in the above
  format or, change the data type of the `Password` column.

**Reference**: [**http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)