# When Inserting into my FormView. the primary key which is a GUID throws a conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, formview

The exception reads

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I'm not really sure where to put the **Convert** function. the code behind page is untouched consisting of an empty **Page_Load**. most of the code was drag and drop from the toolbox. the aspx page is as follows.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="LocalDbExample.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
DataKeyNames="CustomerId" DataSourceID="customerSqlDataSource" 
AllowPaging="True">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                CustomerId:
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
                <br />
                Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                City:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("City") %>' />
                <br />
                State:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("State") %>' />
                <br />
                PostalCode:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PostalCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("PostalCode") %>' />
                <br />
                Notes:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NotesTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Notes") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                CustomerId:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerIdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("CustomerId") %>' />
                <br />
                Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                City:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("City") %>' />
                <br />
                State:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("State") %>' />
                <br />
                PostalCode:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PostalCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("PostalCode") %>' />
                <br />
                Notes:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NotesTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Notes") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                CustomerId:
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
                <br />
                Name:
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                City:
                <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("City") %>' />
                <br />
                State:
                <asp:Label ID="StateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("State") %>' />
                <br />
                PostalCode:
                <asp:Label ID="PostalCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("PostalCode") %>' />
                <br />
                Notes:
                <asp:Label ID="NotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("Notes") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="customerSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM 
[Customers] 
WHERE [CustomerId] = @CustomerId" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] 
([CustomerId], [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [PostalCode], [Notes]) 
VALUES (@CustomerId, @Name, @Address, @City, @State, @PostalCode, @Notes)" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [Name] = @Name, [Address] = @Address, 
[City] = @City, [State] = @State, [PostalCode] = @PostalCode, [Notes] = 
@Notes 
WHERE [CustomerId] = @CustomerId">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Object" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Object" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Object" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The database is one table written as follows.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] (
     [CustomerId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
     [Name]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
     [Address]    VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
     [City]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
     [State]      VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
     [PostalCode] VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
     [Notes]      VARCHAR (MAX)    NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerId] ASC)
 );
```

Comment: What's the datatype of CustomerId in database?

Comment: UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Comment: And you are getting error while displaying the data or while inserting new data to the table?

Comment: This an SQL problem

Comment: the error occurs only when trying to add data. it has something to do with the GUID as the customerID.

Comment: This should probably help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478847/implicit-conversion-from-data-type-sql-variant-to-uniqueidentifier-is-not-allowe?rq=1

Comment: This is what you need: `<asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" DbType="Guid" />`. GUID values are different from plain strings, take care of them properly.

Comment: So i did that and now its saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerId'," when i manually go to insert data the GUID is automatically generated. how can i make it do this when inserting from the app?

Comment: It's a read-only, server generated field. Treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think, since CustomerID is autogenerated, you need to remove it from the "Insert Parameters":

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" Type="Object" />  <-- remove
```